# How do I /tp or /give players at certain coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to build a kit PVP, and to get money for kits you have to sell ores. I don't want to make a generator like in Bedwars because you don't have to stand there, and for coordinates I don't want to have pressure plates on the floors.

Comment: What have you tried already? We can't help you unless you can give us a clear image of what you've tried so far.

Comment: You might be able to use this with a small margin for error
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316885/how-to-target-a-player-that-is-both-in-a-certain-y-coordinate-and-in-a-certain-r#316922

Answer (score 1):

Inside command blocks (and probably the chat, too), you can use `key=value` **arguments**. `x=`, `y=` and `z=` are supported arguments. `r=` can be used to specify the radius around the coordinates to look in.

To select **one** singular player at X=20 and Z=80 (with a 1 block radius/margin):

```
@p[x=20,z=80,r=1]
```

To select **all** entities within 3 blocks of X=-90, Y=64 and Z=0:

```
@e[x=-90,y=64,z=0,r=3]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Say you want to tp to -293 (y?) 789, you would open chat and type:

`/tp [insert name of the person you are wanting to tp] -293 ~ 789.`

Make sure to include this hyphen: `~`.